# JavaScript: Comparing Two Arrays and Replacing Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that I would like to compare against each other based on the `Username` and create a new array that includes `EmployeeName`

```js
let array1 = [{
        OrderID: 30879,
        OrderItems: "Sushi",
        OrderedBy: "johnd",
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30880,
        OrderItems: "Subway",
        OrderedBy: "janes",
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30881,
        OrderItems: "KFC",
        OrderedBy: "alanf",
    },
];

let array2 = [{
        EmployeeName: "John Doe",
        Username: "johnd",
    },
    {
        EmployeeName: "Jane Snow",
        Username: "janes",
    },
    {
        EmployeeName: "Alan Fred",
        Username: "alanf",
    }
]
```

Desired Result:

```js
array3 = [{
        OrderID: 30879,
        OrderItems: "Sushi",
        OrderedBy: "johnd",
        EmployeeName: "John Doe",
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30880,
        OrderItems: "Subway",
        OrderedBy: "janes",
        EmployeeName: "Jane Snow",
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30881,
        OrderItems: "KFC",
        OrderedBy: "alanf",
        EmployeeName: "Alan Fred",
    },
]
```

I've been stuck on this for a while now, how could I best achieve this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple array `map`, with a `find` to get the matching username and the `{...}` spread operator to return the merged object. Probably much like the other responses

```
const combined = array1.map( obj => {
    let e = array2.find(el=>el.Username == obj.OrderedBy).EmployeeName
    return {...obj, EmployeeName: e}
    })
```

```js
let array1 = [{
        OrderID: 30879,
        OrderItems: "Sushi",
        OrderedBy: "johnd"
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30880,
        OrderItems: "Subway",
        OrderedBy: "janes"
    },
    {
        OrderID: 30881,
        OrderItems: "KFC",
        OrderedBy: "alanf"
    }
];

let array2 = [{
        EmployeeName : "John Doe",
        Username : "johnd"
    },
    {
        EmployeeName : "Jane Snow",
        Username : "janes"
    },
    {
        EmployeeName : "Alan Fred",
        Username : "alanf"
    }
];

const combined = array1.map( obj => {
        let e = array2.find(el=>el.Username == obj.OrderedBy).EmployeeName
        return {...obj, EmployeeName: e}
        })

console.log(combined)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store information about each employee such as EmployeeName at each key (being the Username). Then you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your first array and use the `OrderBy` key to grab the associated employee data from the map you made, which you can then spread into the resulting new object:

```js
const array1 = [{ OrderID: 30879, OrderItems: "Sushi", OrderedBy: "johnd", }, { OrderID: 30880, OrderItems: "Subway", OrderedBy: "janes", }, { OrderID: 30881, OrderItems: "KFC", OrderedBy: "alanf", }, ];
const array2 = [{ EmployeeName: "John Doe", Username: "johnd", }, { EmployeeName: "Jane Snow", Username: "janes", }, { EmployeeName: "Alan Fred", Username: "alanf", } ];

const lut = new Map(array2.map(({Username, ...r}) => [Username, r]));
const res = array1.map(obj => ({...obj, ...lut.get(obj.OrderedBy)}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map over the first array and for each item search the second array to retrieve the employee name.

```
const array3 = array1.map(order => ({
  ...order,
  EmployeeName: array2.find(({
    Username
  }) => Username === order.OrderedBy).EmployeeName
}));
```

---

```js
let array1 = [{
    OrderID: 30879,
    OrderItems: "Sushi",
    OrderedBy: "johnd",
  },
  {
    OrderID: 30880,
    OrderItems: "Subway",
    OrderedBy: "janes",
  },
  {
    OrderID: 30881,
    OrderItems: "KFC",
    OrderedBy: "alanf",
  },
];

let array2 = [{
    EmployeeName: "John Doe",
    Username: "johnd",
  },
  {
    EmployeeName: "Jane Snow",
    Username: "janes",
  },
  {
    EmployeeName: "Alan Fred",
    Username: "alanf",
  }
];

const array3 = array1.map(order => ({
  ...order,
  EmployeeName: array2.find(({
    Username
  }) => Username === order.OrderedBy).EmployeeName
}));

console.log(array3)
```